# Having huge gap between header and main category on mobile device

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a problem with distances between elements.
On normal screen sizes the website looks normal, but on mobile devices it creates a huge gap between header and main. I have provided the HTML and CSS code below.

````
    <head>
        <title><?php echo title; ?></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=0.1">
        <link rel="favicon icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/favicon.ico">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <script src="js/fa.js"></script>
        <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js' async defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Header -->
        <div class="header">
            <nav class="navbar">
                <div class="container">
                    <ul class="nav list-group list-group-horizontal">
                    <li class="nav-item nav-item-margin-left">
                        <a class="nav-link hvr-float-shadow" href="index.php">NOUTĂȚI</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item nav-item-margin-left">
                        <a class="nav-link hvr-float-shadow" href="index.php?page=players">CLASAMENT</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item nav-item-margin-left">
                        <a class="nav-link hvr-float-shadow" href="index.php?page=register">REGISTER</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item nav-item-margin-left">
                        <a class="nav-link hvr-float-shadow" href="index.php?page=download">DOWNLOAD</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item nav-item-margin-left">
                        <a class="nav-link hvr-float-shadow" href="<?php echo media['FORUM']; ?>">FORUM</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item nav-item-margin-left">
                        <a class="nav-link hvr-float-shadow" href="index.php?page=itemshop">ITEMSHOP</a>
                    </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav list-group list-group-horizontal pull-sm-right">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">
                        <img src="img/nav-logo.png" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="container main">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-9">
                    <div id="slides" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                        <ul class="carousel-indicators">
                            <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                            <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                            <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="carousel-inner box-radius">
                            <div class="carousel-item active">
                                <img class="box-radius" src="img/slide1.png">
                                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                                    <h5>CREATE NEW ACCOUNT</h5>
                                    <a href="index.php?page=register"><img src="img/joinus.png"></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="box-radius" src="img/slide2.png">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="box-radius" src="img/slide3.png">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#slides" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#slides" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>```
````

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: black;
  color: #705641;
}

.header {
  background: linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    rgb(92, 72, 72) 0%,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 90%,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%), url(../img/bg-top.jpg) center top no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 1300px;
}
```

**Normal View**:

[image: Normal view]

**Mobile View**:

[image: Mobile view]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by changing the viewport from `initial-scale=0.1` to `initial-scale=1.0`
And adding `width=device-width`

Answer (score 0):

It is caused by `height: 100%` on your `.header` element, it takes 100% of the screen height, try using media queries or a different value to adjust the `.header` element height.

Comment: Okey, I'll try it.

Comment: If you can share more info about the expected result on both screens, i would be able to help you with a solution.